# Is it possible for WCF that uses wsDualHttpBinding to be on Https?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, https, push-notification

I implemented a simple `WCF/WPF` project to try out the push notification function of `WCF`. From searches online, they are mostly implemented via callback and using the binding `wsDualHttpBinding`.

However, when trying to implement this PoC project into my main project. I realise the existing `WCF` service is using `Https` and I can't seem to find a way to enable transport security mode for `wsDualHttpBinding` as compared to the existing `wsHttpBinding`.

If the above problem is not solvable, is there another way to implement push notification over `Https` on `WCF`?

Answer (score 0):

If we want to use SSL protocol to encrypt our duplex communication, depending on the practical scenario, we could consider the following binding.

- NetTcpbinding: mainly designed binding for the intranet. If the
  communication is only within the LAN, we could use this binding, it
  supports duplex communication and SSL protocol with a certificate.
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/security-of-nettcpbinding
- NetHttpsbinding: It is a duplex communication across the Internet
  based on websocket protocol, and supports the use of certificates to
  encrypt communications.
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/system-provided-bindings
  Refer to the below example.
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-wcf-service-that-communicates-over-websockets